# I want to change the href link of logo in wordpress website

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, url-routing

I have use roccochoco theme in wordpress and now i want to change the url of logo that other than the home page.
i tried this code but that doesn't work
`$(document).ready(function(){    $("a.custom-logo-link").attr("href", "https://"); });`

please help me out and thanks in advance

Comment: You can do it in the admin dashboard, customize.

If the option is not available. You need to find the php file where the logo is added and change it with your logo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Wordpress using jQuery with `$` often doesn't work, because it is used internally. The console might show you a warning saying "$ is not a function". You can put it inside of a function to make it work. Your element is selected by class, so the name of the class is enough.

```
( function( $ ) {
    $(".custom-logo-link").attr("href", "https://www.newurl.com");
}( jQuery ) );
```

Another way to achieve it without using Javascript would be to edit the **header.php** file of your theme. If you want to keep your theme updatable, you should create a child theme (it is done in one minute with creating an empty folder and putting a style.css with some info in), copy the header.php of your parent theme in the folder and delete the part in the `<a>` tag, looking like `get_home_url()` .

Answer (score 0):

After the DOM is loaded, we  can set the `href` of the anchor having `custom-logo-link` `class` to point to the URL you prefer:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
  jQuery("a.custom-logo-link").attr("href", "https://www.domainname.com"); 
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.